# Threading, Multiprocessing or Asyncio, What suits my project?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm Developing a financial application, that (indirectly) receives live feed from NseIndia every second using websocket-client.

The program structure is composed of multiple Tasks running in parallel.

All of these Tasks require live feeds of various Symbols concurrently.

Each Symbol is a Python Object holding the list of Tasks that have requested that symbol.

The Feed Source Module receives hundreds of feeds every second. It has a method 'distribute()' that segregates the incoming feed and sends it to the respective Symbol. The Symbol then further redistributes the feed to all the Tasks that need it.

To achieve this parallelism I've been using threads of the python threading module.

The problem is that the CPU cannot handle more than 1000 threads at a time, Throwing a

`"RuntimeError: can't start new thread"`

Full Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6542:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC2\PycharmProjects\Feedtest2\Arena\Cerebelle.py", line 49, in quote_distribute
    inx.feed(quote)
  File "C:\Users\PC2\PycharmProjects\Feedtest2\Arena\Instrument.py", line 23, in feed
    Thread(target=sprite.feed, args=(quote,), daemon=True).start()
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 847, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Please suggest a work around or an alternative way to do it!

Thank You!

[A pictorial representation of workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ujO.png)

Comment: 1000 threads is really huge! You should not start so many threads, but use either a pool or a fixed number of threads (one per Task?) getting their inputs from queues. Hard to say more without more details on your projects...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having so many threads you can use a message system (like RabbitMQ, Apache Kafka). Push the messages you get from your websocket on to the appropriate queue and then one or more separate worker processes can process them in the order they were received.